# jquery ui --> toggle draggable div after dragging --> other div moves

Tags: jquery-ui, toggle, drag

I use jquery ui to build a kind of dashboard.

This dashboard contains various divs which should act like "windows": They can be minimized, dragged and maximized.

Everything works fine so far except of the following behavior:

At initial start of the page, window 1 is positioned above window 2.
When i drag window 2 to the right of window 1 and then minimize window 1, window 2 moves out of the screen. It seems that the order of the divs still remain after dragging.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/453a1dh7/3/

```
$('[id^=widget]').draggable({
    snap: true,
    grid: [20, 20]
});
// Widgets skalierbar machen
$('[id^=widget]').resizable({
    snap: true,
    grid: [20, 20]
});

// Widget minimieren
$(".w_minimize").click(function() { 
$(this).closest(".ui-widget-content").find(".body_widget").toggle();
});
```

Please move window 2 to the right of window 1 and then minimize window 1 by pressing the button.

Is there a way to "unlink" the windows so that i can drag and drop them wherever i want and minimizing doesn't affect the position of the other div(s).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to adjust the position within `stop` so that it is not using a relative position to the other elements.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1x9dfa0e/12/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('[id^=widget]').draggable({
    snap: true,
    grid: [20, 20],
    container: ".ui-widget",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log(ui.position, ui.offset);
      ui.helper.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: ui.offset.left + "px",
        top: ui.offset.top + "px"
      });
    }
  });
  // Widgets skalierbar machen
  $('[id^=widget]').resizable({
    snap: true,
    grid: [20, 20]
  });
  // Widget minimieren
  $(".w_minimize").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".ui-widget-content").find(".body_widget").toggle();
  });
});
```

I added a container to help with positioning.

Comment: Hey, that's nearly perfect, thanx a lot!! Do you think it's possible to add the following last function: if i minimize Window 1, move it over window 2 and then maximize it, window 2 gets oberlapped by window 1. is it possible that window 2 gets pished downwards to the "bottom end position" of the maximized window 1? That would be more than perfect ;-) But my programming skills are not good enough to get the solution by myself ;-( Would be great if you could help me one more time

Comment: @DanielBasement that would require collision detection and re-positioning of the surrounding elements. It can be done. I would advise you to mark this question answered, research a bit, and take a stab at it yourself. If you get stuck, open a new question, since it's a new topic.

Answer (score -1):

What about, as workaround, if you set position absolute to second element?

```
div#widget_2 {
 position: absolute !important
}
```

Comment: But what if i have 3 or more windows? And what if i drag window 1 to the right of window 2? In the end i want to give the user the possibillity to activate a custom number of windows (widgets) which can then be freely dragged and resized and minimized.  Means i would need a solution that works with multiple windows and position variations.